# Activity Launcher(File picker) is loading multiple times in single event - Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am using a file picker inside a **HorizontalPager** in jetpack compose. When the corresponding screen is loaded while tapping the button, the launcher is triggered 2 times.

### Code snippet

```
var openFileManager by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
}

if (openFileManager) {
     launcher.launch("*/*")
}

Button(text = "Upload",
        onClick = {
            openFileManager = true
    })
```

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just calling `launch` in your `onClick`? All of this extra ceremony is what is messing you up.

Comment: I assumed the call to launch might be a complicated process for him and he might wish to handle cancellation and stuff, and that is why he created the Boolean. Keeping that in mind, I posted an entire state-hoisting example, but if that is not the case, sir this is an **awful** way of handling a single-shot task. Why even create a Boolean when the only value it is ever going to receive is `true`, and that too being updated only once in the lifecycle of the app??? If this is not the case, however, I urge you to have a look at the solution I posted. It'll easily solve the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited: First of all Ian's point is valid why not just launch it in the onClick directly? I also assumed that maybe you want to do something more with your `true` `false` value. If you want nothing but launch then all these are useless.

The screen can draw multiple times when you click and make `openFileManager` true so using only condition won't prevent it from calling multiple times.

You can wrap your code with `LaunchedEffect` with `openFileManager` as a key. The `LaunchedEffect` block will run only when your `openFileManager` change.

```
if (openFileManager) {
    LaunchedEffect(openFileManager) {
         launcher.launch("*/*")
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just shift the condition inside the effect to let it do it's job normally?

Comment: Going the selective spawning route will only cause unnecessary compositions, leading to performance losses.

Comment: I am really confused about using conditions inside or outside the LaunchedEffect. Maybe once I asked it in the android community but didn't get the answer. Can you tell me the difference and benefit of one over the other?

Comment: I started typing an explanation, but it failed to fit here. Could you simply ask a new question like "Conditional Side-Effect and side-effects with conditions — which is better?" This way more people would also be able to share their views and I'd get to know if I am wrong.

Comment: Ok, Thanks for your suggestion. I will do that when I am free. I use this way because when it's false it won't even call the LaunchedEffect block. But if I use LaunchedEffect outside then when the value is false it will at least run the LaunchedEffect then check the conditional.
I got the idea from this snackbar example though it was in a different context.
https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects#launchedeffect

Comment: That's a valid viewpoint. Post the question when you're free, it'll be fun.

Comment: No, this ordering is the better way to do it - avoiding the `LaunchedEffect` entirely until it is true is much more efficient than unconditionally doing a `LaunchedEffect`.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Wouldn't it need to respawn all the coroutines/threads and be recreated every single time the condition changes? Also, is there a point where the other approach would be comparatively more efficient?

Comment: @RichardOnslowRoper - by including the key on the `LaunchedEffect`, you're restarting it whenever the key changes anyways. The important thing is that you save doing any coroutine creation at all until it becomes true - that creation is comparatively expensive in the first place.

Comment: Alright makes sense. Hey Rafiul, could you please slightly edit your answer so I can remove my downvote? It's locked. Maybe just add a period or something.

Answer (score -1):

You should NEVER store such important state inside a `@Composable`. Such important business logic is meant to be stored in a more robust holder like the `ViewModel`.

```
ViewModel{
  var launch by mutableStateOf (false)
  private set
 
  fun updateLaunchValue(newValue: Boolean){
    launch = newValue
  }
}
```

Pass these to the Composable from the main activity

```
MyComposable(
  launchValue = viewModel.launch
  updateLaunchValue = viewModel::updateLaunchValue
)
```

Create the parameters in the Composable as necessary

```
@Comoosable
fun Uploader(launchValue: Boolean, onUpdateLaunchValue: (Boolean) -> Unit){
  LaunchedEffect (launchValue){
    if (launchValue)
      launcher.launch(...)
  }
  
  Button { // This is onClick
    onUpdateLaunchValue(true) // makes the value true in the vm, updating state
  }
}
```

If you think it is overcomplicated, you're in the wrong paradigm. This is the recommended AND CORRECT way of handling state in Compose, or any declarative paradigm, really afaik. This keeps the code clean, while completely separating UI and data layers, allowing controlled interaction between UI and state to achieve just the perfect behaviour for the app.